# Evaluating a double integral involving exponential of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am having trouble evaluating the following double integral:

$$\int\limits_0^\pi\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\exp\left[a\sin\theta\cos\psi+b\sin\theta\sin\psi+c\cos\theta\right]\sin\theta d\theta\, d\psi$$

I will be satisfied with an answer involving special functions (e.g. modified Bessel function).

I tried expanding the product terms using the product-to-sum identities, as well applied other [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_identity), to no avail.  Can anyone help?

I suspect that the solution will involve a modified Bessel function $I_n(x)$ with argument in the form $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$.  The reason I think so is because the above integral is related to a likelihood function used in evaluation of a non-coherent detection of signals that are corrupted by additive white Gaussian noise (for example, see Proakis "Digital Communications" 4th Edition pp. 304-306). However, these signals are in the two-dimensional domain (they are complex numbers) and the corresponding integral is as follows: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\exp[a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta]d\theta=2\pi I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$.  The double integral that I am trying to evaluate is the extension of this problem to a three-dimensional space, with the corresponding change from polar to [spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}a \sin{\theta} \cos{\psi} + b \sin{\theta} \sin{\psi}  &=  (a \cos{\psi} + b \sin{\psi}) \sin{\theta}\\ &= \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos{(\psi- \psi_0)} \sin{\theta} \end{align}$$

where

$$\tan{\psi_0} = \frac{b}{a}$$

Now, when we integrate the periodic function over $\psi \in [0,2 \pi)$, the result does not depend on $\psi_0$ and we get

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\psi \: e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin{\theta} \cos{(\psi- \psi_0)}} = \int_0^{2 \pi} d\psi \: e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin{\theta} \cos{\psi}}$$

This turns out to be

$$2 \pi I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin{\theta})$$

Now the integral is

$$\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \sin{\theta} I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin{\theta}) e^{c \cos{\theta}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I am confused by statement "The integral is independent of $\psi$ for the same reason as you find in the 2d polar integral", as I am not sure how one gets rid of $\psi$.  Am I missing some trig identity?  Again, thanks!

Comment: @M.B.M. I will elaborate.

Comment: @M.B.M.: I am afraid I spoke too soon; when actually working the problem through, i found an error I had made.  Not sure if what you have is true in general.

Comment: Hmm, this is the problem I was having as well (not being to get rid of the modified Bessel in the integral).  However, I didn't get the $\sin\theta$ in front of the $I_0(\cdot)$, just inside...

Comment: I just went through G&R, no dice.  Perhaps there is a way to circumvent this?  As I said in OP, I'd like to extend the non-coherent detection from 2d to 3d.  My conjecture is that one should still use square-law (i.e. test statistic $a^2+b^2+c^2$). To prove this I need to show that the integral in my OP evaluates to a function that is monotonically non-decreasing with $a^2+b^2+c^2$ for real $a$, $b$, $c$.  If I do this, I'll be well on the way towards answering a question that long riddled me: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20146/is-this-hypothesis-test-somehow-optimal

Comment: The integral I have written down is the best I could do. By the way, note that you forgot a factor of $\sin{\theta}$ in the integral.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  This may be a very dumb question, but where did that factor of $\sin\theta$ come from?  Per definition of modified Bessel, $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{r\cos\psi}d\psi=2\pi I_0(r)$, and in this case $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\theta$.  So the final integral I get is $2\pi\int_0^{\pi} I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\theta)e^{c\sin\theta}d\theta$...

Comment: You are integrating over the surface of a sphere.  An area element in spherical coordinates is $dA = \sin{\theta} d\theta d\psi$.  You are integrating over the surface of a unit sphere

Comment: Ahh, so you are saying that I am missing the factor $\sin\theta$ in the original integral?

Comment: @M.B.M.: correct.

Comment: I see, thanks!  I didn't remember this from my calculus class (long time ago)...  Reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates), this (sort of) makes sense.  Looks like one must insert $\sin$ term taken to the power $i-2$ for every angle except the last one when dealing with [$n$-sphere surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)...  I am used to working in polar coordinates and haven't encountered this...

Comment: I think I solved it -- see my answer and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First, I would like to thank Ron Gordon for the partial answer above, and, very importantly, for pointing out the error in the original formulation question in the comments.  Here I show a closed-form expression for the last integral in his answer:

$$\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \sin{\theta} I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin{\theta}) e^{c \cos{\theta}}$$

Let $t=-\cos\theta$.  Then $dt=d\theta\sin\theta$, $\theta=\arccos(-t)\Rightarrow\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-t^2}$, and the limits of integration $\{-1,1\}$.  Substitution all of this yields the following integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}I_0(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{1-t^2})e^{-ct}dt$$

Gradshteyn&Ryzhik, 7th edition has the following integral as formula 6.616.5: $\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-ax}I_0(b\sqrt{1-x^2})dx=2(a^2+b^2)^{-1/2}\sinh\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Thus, the integral in my question evaluates to:

$$\frac{2\sinh\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Comment: If this is correct numerically, then this is awesome! How is application to signals going?

Comment: @You'reInMyEye This was long time ago!  :)  I think it worked for the case I was evaluating.  Certainly computed a lot faster than the integral...

Comment: M.B.M. Still very nice. I'm trying to see if this may be useful for quantum mechanics applications.