# Integrating $e^{a\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)+b\cos(\phi_1-\phi_3)+c\cos(\phi_2-\phi_3)}$ over $[0,2\pi]^3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate the following function. (it arises in channel modeling in wireless communications, Rayleigh random variables)..Any help is appreciated.Thanks

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{a\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)+b\cos(\phi_1-\phi_3)+c\cos(\phi_2-\phi_3)}d\phi_1d\phi_2d\phi_3$$

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/361902/269624)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I checked that question already.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Note that your integrand is periodic in all the integration variables. We will use this fact later.

Let us introduce the new variables $x_1= \phi_1- \phi_2$, $x_2 = \phi_2 -\phi_3$ and $x_3 = \phi_3-\phi_1$. We immediately notice that $x_3 = - x_1 - x_2$. The goal is thus, to perform a change of variables from $(\phi_1, \phi_2 , \phi_3)$ to $(X, x_1, x_2)$ with $X=(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)/3$. The Jacobian for this change is given by $|\det J|=  1$.

It would be most convenient, if the new integration region would be again $[0,2\pi]^3$. I will argue that this is correct due to the fact (1).

Here, I have shown the analog situation for a change of variable $(\phi_1,\phi_2)\mapsto(X,x_1)$ with $X=(\phi_1+\phi_2)/2$ and $x_1 =\phi_1-\phi_2$ involving only two of the three variables.
[image]

The original integration region $(\phi_1,\phi_2)\in[0,2\pi]^2$ is shown in blue. The new region $(X,x_1) \in [0,2\pi]^2$ is in red. It can be immediately seen that due to the $2\pi$ periodicity of the integrand, integration over these two regions yields the same result.

A simular result can be obtained for all three variables (the corresponding plot would be in a dimension higher).

So we have that
$$I=\int_{[0,2\pi]^3} \!d\phi_1\,d\phi_2\,d\phi_3 e^{a \cos(\phi_1-\phi_2) + b \cos (\phi_2-\phi_3) + c\cos(\phi_3-\phi_1)}= \int_{[0,2\pi]^3}\!dX\,dx_1\,dx_2 e^{a \cos(x_1) + b \cos(x_2) + c\cos(x_1+x_2)}.$$

The integral over $X$ is trivial (yielding $2\pi$).

Next, we perform the integral over $x_1$. We need the result that
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\!dx_1 e^{a \cos(x_1) + c \cos(x_1+x_2)} = 2 \pi I_0\left(\sqrt{a^2+c^2+2 a c \cos(x_2)}\right)$$ 
with $I_0$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind. The result can be proven using $\cos(x_1+x_2) = \cos(x_1) \cos(x_2) -\sin(x_1) \sin(x_2)$ and the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion).

So, we have that
$$I = (2\pi)^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \! dx_2\,e^{b \cos(x_2)} I_0\left(\sqrt{a^2+c^2+2 a c \cos(x_2)}\right).$$

This last integral, I don't know if it can be evaluated explicitly. I would guess that this could be another question ...

*Edit:*

Using Graf's addition theorem for Bessel function, I managed to bring the integral onto the alternative form
$$ I = (2\pi)^3 \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} I_k(a) I_k(b) I_k(c).$$
I am not sure if this is simpler though.

Comment: Do you think [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/362768/269624) might be helpful? The integral is a little different there though

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: the integral looks sufficiently different that I would expect that it is not helpful. But that is only my feeling...

Comment: When you made the substitution X=$(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3$ is equal to zero. Therefore, all of the partial derivatives for the Jacobian is zero, hence the determinant of the Jacobian is zero. Correct me if I am wrong. Also infinite expansion of bessel functions may be correct but I am looking for an expression where I can actually make some calculations. 

I have come up to the point where you have only one integration left as well but can not seem to progress from there. I am going to keep checking. Thanks.

Comment: $X=x_3=-\phi_1-\phi_2-\phi_3$ would work with |J|=3. But anyway, that is not where the actual problem I am having.

Comment: I have solved the problem and It is very much like what Fabian posted. Infinite series of products of Bessel functions.