# integration by parts of multiple functions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

Can anyone help me solve this problem? $I_0$ represents the modified Bessel function.Thanks.

$$\int_{a-b}^{a+b}\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{c\,t^2}{2ab}\right)\,t\,I_0(t)}{ab\sqrt{1-\frac{(t^2-a^2-b^2)^2}{4a^2b^2}}}dt$$

Comment: Solved here (same problem, different formulation): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866848/integrating-ea-cos-phi-1-phi-2b-cos-phi-1-phi-3c-cos-phi-2-phi-3