# Does this summation converge? if so to what?

Tags: limits, summation

$\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}\sum_{c=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a+b)!(a + c )!(b + c)!
   ((y - 1)(2x^2 - y - 1))^2(x^2 - y)^{2c}
   (x(y - 1))^{2a + 2b})}{
         a!^2b!^2c!^2(1 - y^2)^{a + b + 1}
   (1 - x^2)^{a + b + 2c + 2}}$

given $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$

Thanks

Comment: Care to give some context?

Comment: Yeah, I am working on triple variate Rayleigh distribution. Once I found an expression in terms of infinite series of bessel functions, I integrated over all three variables and came up with the expression above. This is one of the two terms therefore I am expecting this expression to converge to somewhere between 0-1. Does that help?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866848/integrating-ea-cos-phi-1-phi-2b-cos-phi-1-phi-3c-cos-phi-2-phi-3?noredirect=1#comment3824048_1866848

Comment: You should include that info in question.

Comment: Looks like the sum equals to $\displaystyle\;-\frac{1+y-2x^2}{(1-y)\sqrt{(1+y)^2-4x^2}}$

Comment: I will have to look at this carefully to understand how you approached this. Thank you very much. I appreciate the help. I just realized that I forgot to include a square ((y-1) term in the numerator should be (y-1)^2) in my original question but I do not think It will change the method you try to solve it.

Comment: Can you please specify region of convergence ?

Comment: I posted the complete question here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024566/show-that-the-summation-equals-to-1?noredirect=1#comment4155282_2024566

Comment: Can you give me a reference book or something to learn how to compute these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer updated to reflect change in question.

---

Let $A_{ab} = \frac{(a+b)!}{a!b!}$ . The sum at hand has the form

$$\frac{(1-y)^2(1+y-2x^2)^2}{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)^2}F\left(\frac{x^2(1-y)^2}{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)},\;\frac{x^2(1-y)^2}{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)},\;\frac{(x^2-y)^2}{(1-x^2)^2}\right)\tag{*1}$$

where

$$F(u,v,w) = \sum_{a=0}^\infty \sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{c=0}^\infty A_{ab} A_{bc}  A_{ca} u^a v^b w^c
$$
For any $\rho > 0$, let $D_\rho = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le \rho \}$ and
$C_\rho = \partial D_\rho = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = \rho \}$ be the closed disk/circle of radius $\rho$ centered at origin. Let $R = \frac12$ and pick an $r \in (0,\frac14)$.

For any $u \in D_r$ and $p, q \in C_R$, we have following converging power series expansion.

$$\frac{1}{1 - up^{-1} - q} = \sum_{a=0}^\infty\sum_{b=0}^\infty A_{ab} u^a p^{-a} q^b$$

Together with following representation of [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) as a contour integral

$$\delta_{ab} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C_R} \frac{dp}{p} p^{a-b}$$

We find for $u, v, w \in D_r$, we can rewrite $F(u,v,w)$ as a triple contour integral:

$$\begin{align}F(u,v,w)
&= \sum_{a,a'=0}^\infty \sum_{b,b'=0}^\infty \sum_{c,c'=0}^\infty
( u^a A_{ab'})\delta_{b'b}(v^b A_{bc'})\delta_{c'c}(w^c A_{ca'})\delta_{a'a}\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^3}
\oint_{C_R}\oint_{C_R}\oint_{C_R} \frac{dpdqds}{
(p(1-q)-u)(q(1-s) - v)(s(1-p) - w)
}
\end{align}
$$
As long as $u, v, w \in D_r$, there are one and only one pole within $C_R$ for each layer of contour integration. It is not that hard to carry out the integral and the end result is

$$F(u,v,w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-u-v-w)^2-4uvw}}\tag{*2}$$

Since the closest singularity of $F(u,v,w)$ to origin is located at $(u,v,w) = \left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14\right)$, our choice of $r < \frac14$ cannot be improved anymore.

Substitute $(*2)$ back into $(*1)$. As long as $3x^2 - 1 < 2y < 1 + x^2$, we have
$$\left|\frac{x^2(1-y)^2}{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}\right|,\;\left|\frac{(x^2-y)^2}{(1-x^2)^2}\right| < \frac14$$ 
and the sum evaluates to
$$\frac{1+y-2x^2}{\sqrt{(1+y)^2-4x^2}}$$